# Java Text tag replacer code

Tags: java, pattern-matching

In my mind, this seemed straigtforward...right up to the point that I sat down and started typing.

Anyway, I've been tasked with writing a method that will find "tags" in a String, and replace them appropriately, outputting the resultant string. The function declaration would look something like:

```
public String doStuff(String source, Map<Integer, String> replacementData)
```

The idea is that each "tag" will be an integer value surrounded in "<<>>" (so the regex is something like ".*<<[0-9]+>>.*"). Once one of these tags is encountered in `source`, the integer I contained within the tag should be harvested from the tag, and the tag should be replaced via `replacementData.get(I)`

Anyway, I'd like to do this efficiently. I'm just not sure how to go about it. I took a look at Pattern and Matcher, and I don't think that that was the right route. I'd prefer not to use String.indexOf and stuff like that, because it is inefficient (isn't it?).

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What's wrong with using pattern/matcher? It's pretty fast.

Comment: This has all the symptoms of premature optimization in the works, you know... Make a program that works first, profile it, and optimize if necessary. I bet it wouldn't be necessary, because it is hard to butcher a tag replacer into inefficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it with Regex Pattern and Matcher is to capture the integer in what is known as a group and then use that to replace. 
The other interesting part of your problem is the step by step replacement. The sequence of steps that you need to do are described in the javadoc for [appendReplacement method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Example Code:

```
String str = "abc<<1>>def<<2>>ghi";
java.util.Map<Integer,String> replacementMap = new java.util.HashMap<Integer,String>() {
    {
        put(1," ONE ");
        put(2," TWO ");
    }
};
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<<([0-9]+)>>");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
int start = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb,replacementMap.get(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output: `abc ONE def TWO ghi`

Comment: Gave it a test run (sorry it took so long). Looks like it works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation:

```
public String doStuff(String source, Map<Integer, String> replacementData){

    for( Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : replacementData.entrySet() )
         source = source.replace("<<"+entry.getKey().toString()+">>", entry.getValue() );

    return source;
}
```

<del>It doesn't look too inefficient to me. The only way to make it more efficient is to try to complete everything in one pass over the string, but that would involve practically rewriting `String.replace()`.</del>

<del>Considering the amount of work that would go into it, I would put this sort of optimization in the category of something to do only if a profiler shows that this is a real bottleneck.</del>

The `Matcher`-based method by Puneet is better since it only passes over the string once.